# User on wrong session

Tags: asp.net, session, caching, load-balancing

I've found articles that describe issues similar to mine but not close enough. I have a really intermittent problem where one user can land on another users session and end up seeing some of their information that's stored in a session. Here's my scenario: We use AbleCommerce in a load balanced environment using Application Request Routing and Web Farm Framework. We use in-proc sessions but we have sticky sessions (client/server affinity) configured and working. I've verified there is no caching causing this issue (nothing using page output cache, no ARR caching, no IIS or WAAS caching). The information stored in the session that very occasionally ends up on someone elses browser is stored in the session via a session based singleton object.

For Example:

```
public class ExampleObject
{
    public string ExampleData{get; set;}

    public static TicketingSession Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ExampleObject"] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["ExampleObject"] = new ExampleObject();
            }
            return (ExampleObject)HttpContext.Current.Session["ExampleObject"];
        }
    }
}
```

And then in some other code I can use this:

```
ExampleObject.Instance.ExampleData = "whatever";
//or
txtSomeTextBox.Text = ExampleObject.Instance.ExampleData;
```

I know I should steer clear of static data and in-proc sessions in load balanced environments but since I'm using client/server affinity and since this static object I'm using is just a property whos getter simply returns the object directly from the session state I don't see an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move away from inproc session when in a web farming scenario. You need to use an out of process session store to ensure the `Session ID` is unique.

ASP.NET stores its `Session ID` in the browser's cookie collection. If the users have the same `Session ID` their sessions will appear the same to the server. Using separate servers, or even worker processes on the same server, can result in these types of `Session ID` collisions.

You can get more detail via [MSDN on various Session-State modes supported by ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx).

Comment: I agree that obviously if two users end up on the same server with the same id they would see the same data because the server sees them as the same user. However in my case that would require ARR to mess-up and send the second user to the first users server after it had assigned the second user a different server. If they were assigned the same server then load balancing would be irrelevant because that means one server gave two users the same session id. Is ARR known to have that kind of an issue? It would explain a viewstate validation error i get intermittently too.

Comment: I should mention we've tested our ARR affinity with an aspx file that shows you what server you landed on. You can reload it all you want but until the affinity cookie is lost or removed you always end up on the same server.

Comment: We've switched over to storing the session state in SQL. It appears to be working as intended. I'll mark this as an answer if we don't have anymore of these issues in the future. Thanks for the help!!